# How to access particular value after angularjs's form submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My form start like that :

```
    <!-- form -->
    <form ng-submit="form.submit()" class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="margin-top: 15px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputUrl" class="col-sm-2 control-label">URL</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUrl" name="inputUrl" ng-model="form.url" />
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

and the attached js controller start like this :

```
$scope.form = {};

$scope.form.submit = function() {

        console.log($scope.form);
        var url = $scope.form[url];
        console.log("Url is  " + url);
}
```

the url var is undefined in the console, what is the good way ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you missed the name attribute in the form tag check it:

```
<!-- form -->
<form ng-submit="form.submit()" class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="margin-top: 15px;" name="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUrl" class="col-sm-2 control-label">URL</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUrl" name="url" ng-model="form.url" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```